# Total probability for expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that $$\mathbb{E} [ \sum_{k=1}^{X_0}] = \lambda^2$$

with  $\lambda_{0}=\lambda_{1}...=\lambda_n=: \lambda$ with $X_{i} \sim $Poi$ (\lambda_{i}), \lambda_{i} > 0, i \in \mathbb{N} $ $X_{i}$ are independent with the $(X_{0},...,X_{n}): \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a multivariate random variable.

I'm still totally struggling with this problem, should I eventually generate a tree diagram to show this problem? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, $x_0$ is supposed to be $X_0$ and perhaps, $X_i$'s are supposed to be independent.

Comment: thank you I edited the question

Comment: LHS is $\lambda EX_0$ (by conditioning on $X_0$) and $EX_0=\lambda$.

Comment: please, fix the expression of the question, as written is meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditioning on $X_0$: $\mathbb E[ \sum_{k=1}^{X_0} X_k] = \sum_{\ell\ge 1} \mathbb E[ \sum_{k=1}^{X_0} X_k \mid X_0 = \ell] \mathbb P(X_k = \ell) \\= \sum_{\ell \ge 1}  (\ell \lambda) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^\ell}{\ell!}$,

where we used independence and linearity of expectation.

We can rewrite this as $\lambda \sum_{\ell \ge 0} \ell e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^\ell}{\ell!} = \lambda E[X_0] = \lambda^2$, or more directly just shifting the sum: $\lambda \sum_{\ell \ge 1}e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{\ell}}{(\ell-1)!} =\lambda e^{-\lambda} \sum_{\ell \ge 0} \frac{\lambda^{\ell+1}}{\ell!} = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}\sum_{\ell \ge 0} \frac{\lambda^{\ell}}{\ell!}=\lambda^2 $.

Comment: could you eventually give a bit more detailed explanation to the very last part of your solution? I mean from shifting the sum because it's not clear to me how does it work.